# What overhead is incurred in python's reduce implementation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, clojure, clojurescript

I have some python scripts that were taking longer than I expected, so I started investigating and found some surprises in python's performance. Mostly, it seems to revolve around `reduce`, but I don't understand why.

To experiment, I wrote the following two modules:

`py.py`

```
from functools import reduce

def mysum(n):
    return reduce(lambda acc, x: acc + x, range(n + 1))

n = int(1e8)
print(mysum(n))
```

and

`clj.clj`

```
(defn mysum [n]
  (reduce + (range (inc n))))

(println (mysum 1e8))
```

I compared their performance using `time`:

```
➜  ~ time python py.py
5000000050000000
python py.py  21.90s user 0.41s system 95% cpu 23.344 total
➜  ~ time lumo clj.clj
5000000050000000
lumo clj.clj  2.44s user 0.13s system 102% cpu 2.519 total
```

It appears that python is performing over 10x slower than the clojure implementation. But that is the opposite of what I expected.

Even when running the clj file using the JVM, which incurs significant startup costs, python is beat by a mile:

```
➜  ~ time clj clj.clj
5000000050000000
clj clj.clj  6.01s user 0.72s system 153% cpu 4.394 total
```

Why is python's reduce so slow here? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with Python's `reduce`? If you use an explicit loop instead of `reduce`, I'll bet the difference is about the same. If you compare Clojure for JVM to Jython or PyPy instead of CPython, I'll bet it goes away. Or, say, ClojureJS vs. PyJS. If my guesses are right, you're just comparing how fast JIT-compiled low-level bytecode runs vs. no-JIT high-level bytecode, which isn't very interesting.

Comment: I'm no pythonista, so this may be silly,  but that range call isn't allocating a big sequence, right?  It's just creating the generator, I hope? What are the times like if outs only the reduction, and not the call to range? I know you tagged with python 3, but...

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor yeah it's py3, so the range call produces a generator. Sounds like it's apparently nothing to do with reduce at all, and instead everything to do with compilation.

Comment: Technically it produces a `range` object, not a generator.

Comment: For a small win, you can replace the python lambda with `operator.add`. But as already mentioned there are better ways to calculate this particular sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your python code is being interpreted, whereas the Clojure code is being compiled on the JVM by the HotSpot compiler.  That is a big advantage of being on the JVM and the reason Python & Ruby have ports Jython & JRuby on the JVM, respectively.

Simple sums are even faster in native Java:  Here are some quick comparisons:

```
class Calc {
  public static long cumsum( long limit ) {
    long result = 0;
    for (long i=0; i<limit; i++) {
      result += i;
    }
    return result;
  }

(let [limit 1e8]
  (newline) (println :result-clj)
  (crit/quick-bench (reduce + (range limit)))

(newline) (println :result-java-cumsum)
(crit/quick-bench (Calc/cumsum limit)))

:result-clj             Execution time mean : 1777.600 ms
:result-java-cumsum     Execution time mean :   26.920399 ms
```

Yes, that is a 66x speedup.  Try reducing the count to `1e6`.

```
:result-clj             Execution time mean : 17572.885 µs
:result-java-cumsum     Execution time mean :   257.092 µs
```

Another trick is that the Hotspot Compiler can often recognize a sum from 1..N and substitute in the algebraic formula

```
sum(1..N) => N*(N+1)/2
```

which has no looping at all!

Comment: That last bit about algebra substitution is particularly cool.

Answer (score -1):

As I remember, range makes a list, whereas xrange produces iterable. Nevertheless, I've tried to replace it and it didn't help. So yes, it seems the key problem here is related to interpreter nature. 
By the way, this one works pretty quickly -
sum(xrange(100000001))

Comment: The OP tagged Python 3, which doesn't have `range` produce a full list.